# Multiple transactions for a database save or a single bulk save

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, transactions

Looking for recommendations / opinions on this one. Do you think its better to save all the items in a single database transaction, or to save each item in its own transaction, the items have sub items etc... so they need to be saved in a transaction but the entire group/list does not. Almost everyone I would assume would just do a bulk save but I was curious. Sample pseudo code below for each.

Single Transaction:

```
    BeginTransaction()

    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        items[i].Save();

    CommitTransaction()
```

Multiple Transactions:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
    {
      BeginTransaction()
      items[i].Save();
      CommitTransaction() 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably determined better by the requirements of what happens when one of those transactions fails. If the transactions are related and they should *all* fail, then put the transaction outside of the loop. If they are discrete transactions, and one failing shouldn't fail the others, put them inside the loop (and catch the failure and `continue` or `break` as appropriate).

If that doesn't matter, and you're strictly interested in a performance perspective, transactions do add overhead. How much slower is a function of a great number of variables, including the individual query size and performance, database type and configuration, and hardware/virtualization resources. It could be trivial/unmeasurable for slow queries (where the query itself takes the bulk of the time) or very large (for trivial queries).

How much is up to you to measure.

Comment: In this case the item requires the transaction only, the list not so much as a whole. So the items are also fast to save, not slow at all. So basically the measurement I assume is just the total length of the list save to determine if the transaction is open for too long. Ok thanks just re-evaluates what im thinking.